# TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'continuous'

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I'm trying to convert speech to text using IBM Watson. There's a keyword argument not getting recognized in the `stt.recognize()` function.

Here's my code:

```
# Perform conversion
with open('data/197587532_1.wav', 'rb') as f:
    res = stt.recognize(audio=f, content_type='audio/wav', model='en-US_NarrowbandModel', continuous=True).get_result()

TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'continuous'
```

When trying without `continuous=True`, I get this error message:

```
{'error': 'No speech detected for 30s.',
 'code': 400,
 'code_description': 'Bad Request'}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Comment: What makes you think `stt.recognize` accepts a `continuous` argument…?

Answer (score 2):

Check the API documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#recognize

There is no `continuous` argument, but there is an `inactivity_timeout` argument.

> The time in seconds after which, if only silence (no speech) is
> detected in the audio, the connection is closed. The default is 30
> seconds. The parameter is useful for stopping audio submission from a
> live microphone when a user simply walks away. Use -1 for infinity.